# Resetting sprite node in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am having a simple game in which if user goes to background, the game upon starting has to hide the player sprite node.

My code is as follows:

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    [super didMoveToView:view];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidEnterBackground:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)appDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self hidePlayerNode];
}

- (void)hidePlayerNode
{
   [self.playerNode runAction:[SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:0.0]];
}
```

The problem is that when the game is launched from background, I can see the player node for a split second and then it disappears. I need to make the player node invisible, the moment it goes to background and user shouldn't see it when the app is relaunched.

I tried with `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` but the result is the same. Also, I tried running the code inside the selector method by main thread, but same result again.

Comment: Have you tried using the applicationWillResignActive method and instead of an alpha fade using "playerNode.hidden = true;" ?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably seeing the state of your app that was saved as you went into the background.

Apple docs: "When your applicationDidEnterBackground: method returns, the system takes a picture of your app’s user interface and uses the resulting image for transition animations. If any views in your interface contain sensitive information, you should hide or modify those views before the applicationDidEnterBackground: method returns."